# Antialiasing with Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

We are building a 3d-room in which different objects or furnitures are placed. We are going to display it on a big flatscreen. 
Because of other shaders we are using the fxaa-shader but its result is pretty insufficient. The models are really highpoly.

We have also adapted super sampling for testing purposes, but the result is still not as good as we hoped.

I have read about the SMAA. But as far as I have seen there is no WebGL-Port for it, right?

Does anybody know how to get SMAA up and running with Three.JS?

Kind regards
Dan

Comment: Super sampling is not good enough? Something is wrong then. Try doing combined SSAA x4-x8 and FXAA?

Answer (score 1):

I am very late in answering this question, but there is support for SMAA in Threejs. You can find an example here: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_smaa.html